# Error while querying workflow rules using tooling api

Tags: workflow, metadata, query, tooling-api

I am trying to run the following query in my developer console (using tooling api):
SELECT Id,Name,NamespacePrefix,Metadata FROM WorkflowRule 
but get an error saying 'An unexpected error occurred.'

It works fine if I remove the metadata field and run the following query: SELECT Id,Name,NamespacePrefix FROM WorkflowRule

Am I missing anything? Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: When I run the second query from the developer console "query editor" I get "sObject type 'WorkflowRule' is not supported.". (Perhaps I am missing a step in this to use the "tooling api"; please add that step to the question if I am.)

Comment: There will be a checkbox 'use tooling api' towards the bottom of the screen that needs to be checked.

Comment: @PriyanshiAgrawal Where you able to get through metadata information too using tooling api query ?

Comment: @ChiragMehta Yes, I was able to get the metadata information after the last Salesforce release.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is quite old now, but I'll post this here for those who still come across this question:

You can only retrieve the metadata from one workflow rule at a time.  If you look at the Salesforce "Workflowrule" documentation under the tooling API at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_workflowrule.htm#!, you will notice that under Metadata it says

> Query this field only if the query result contains no more than one
>   record. Otherwise, an error is returned. If more than one record
>   exists, use multiple queries to retrieve the records. This limit
>   protects performance.

As such, in order to return that Metadata, your query should contain a where clause so that it only returns ONE and ONLY ONE workflow.